# Shutdown Spring boot application after zookeeper connection is lost

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, shutdown

I am running a spring boot application in a clustered zookeeper setup . I am using leader election to ensure that only one instance of the springboot application is running. Once the leader goes down , then other node(follower) takes up the leader and starts the process. If the leader goes down because we shutdown the application , then new leader can run. but if the network is lost with the leader then the process in the old leader will be still running and a new leader will also run. So two instances will be running. Is there a way to stop the application in the old leader? or am i asking a wrong question. I am new to springboot and zookeeper. Correct me if i am wrong!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `spring-boot-actuator`. It has a `/shutdown` endpoint that does exactly what it says on the tin. Note this endpoint is not enabled by default so you need to enable it by setting the following in `application.properties`:

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

You probably want to configure some security around this too, as it's not a wise idea to let anyone just shut down your application.

For more info see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)